# add Login and Singup to an existing android project

Tags: android, authentication, sharedpreferences

How can I add a signup and login activity to my existing project using shared preferences?
I already changed AndroidManifest.xml and set the loginActivity to be LAUNCHER activity.
my main problem is that I don't know how to write and work with shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Please get acquainted with - https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

It is **MUST-TO-KNOW** basics :)

It is very simple

To set signed user use:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("USERNAME_KEY", userName);
editor.apply();
```

And to get it use:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int highScore = sharedPref.getInt("USERNAME_KEY", "Unknown");
```

***But SP - is not the best solution for authentication!***